# Chrome extension or chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api, google-chrome-app

I would like to create an extension or app for the Chrome browser which would require access to a user's Google Calender (for creating new appointments).

I am unsure of which technology to better research and use, Chrome extensions or apps. My *"app"* wouldn't need much of a GUI, so I'm leaning towards extension — but I don't know if this would pose any difficulties for accessing a user's Google Calender to add an event.

Anyone one have any idea which technology is best for this situation, and why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either, or... Go with an extension if you'd like.

I assume you've looked at the API reference?
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

From there, I'd imagine you'd just need OAuth to authenticate the user. Here's the JS library:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/

Comment: No, actually. But this is just the information I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are pros/cons of each types, apps or extensions.

- Apps

  - If you would like to create a client application of Google Calendar which has many rich GUI components, this type will become a better solution.
  - In addition, Chrome apps can communicate with many hardware devices and other servers. Of course, your Chrome app can become as a server (that is, your app can open a server socket and accept a request from other client apps).
  - Chrome apps can be executed not depending on your Chrome Web browser. That is, Chrome apps cannot access to a context of your Chrome Web browser.

Probably, you don't want to get the pros above, I guess...

- Extensions

  - If you would like to create a small UI for posting your schedule to Google Calendar, this type will become a better solution.
  - In addition, Chrome extensions can access to a context of your Chrome Web browser. That is, your extension can get page contents of each tab and inject your CSS and/or JS code. For example, your extension will get a URL of some opened tab and include it in a body of the posted schedule.
  - Chrome extensions completely depend on your Chrome Web browser. That is, your extension cannot execute independently.

Also, generally, high cost will be needed to develop Chrome apps than Chrome extensions. As the result, you should choose Chrome extensions, I believe.